# Common keyword to 'continue' in sequential and parallel for loops

Tags: c++11, for-loop, visual-c++, parallel.for

In a sequential `for` loop, the current iteration can be interrupted by calling `continue`. Similarly, in a `Concurrency::parallel_for` loop, the current iteration - which is a thread calling a lambda function - can be interrupted with `return`.

From time to time, it happens that I have to debug a `parallel_for` loop, make it sequential and forget to change the `return` into a `continue`, because in a `void` function, the compiler won't complain. This leads to errors that are really hard to track down sometimes.

I wonder if Visual C++ 2013 offers any mechanism to use the same keyword/macro/… for both loops. Is this possible?

Comment: You could of course define your own macro

Comment: Any suggestion on how to do that? It would have to depend on the current scope, i.e. for or parallel_for, right?

Comment: It's ugly, but possible...
`#define EXIT_CURRENT_LOOP_ITERATION continue` 
`#define EXIT_CURRENT_LOOP_ITERATION return` 
Define the one you need

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Since you're using the sequential loop only for debugging, you could transform into a version that also uses a lambda:

```
parallel_for (first, last, [&](size_t i)
{
    if(condition)
        return;
    do_stuff(i);
});
```

Transforms into

```
for (size_t i = first; i < last; i++)[&]
{
    if(condition)
        return;
    do_stuff(i);
}();
```

It's ugly, sure. But it's not going to stay that way if it only exists for debugging.

---

Or, you could wrap all your lambda functions in a loop that does a single iteration, and always use `continue` instead of `return`. The downside is that you uglify the non-debug code.

```
parallel_for (first, last, [&](size_t i)
{
    do {
        if(condition)
            continue; // same as return
        do_stuff(i);
    } while(0);
});
```

Works the same in the sequential form:

```
for (size_t i = first; i < last; i++)
{
    do {
        if(condition)
            continue; // same as continue without the do/while
        do_stuff(i);
    } while(0);
}
```

Comment: Hey, I was not aware that the first suggestion actually works. Yes, it is a bit ugly, but since it's only for debugging, I'll accept this as a solution for my problem.